# StreamReader encoding (bug?)

Tags: powershell, streamreader

I am running into what seems to be a bug, but could also be my ignorance. I have a file that I know to be Unicode encoding, per Notepad++, but when using this Powershell code, I get back UTF8. My understanding is that this constructor for StreamReader, with True in the second argument, gets the encoding from the file itself, and CurrentEncoding is the way to access that. My hope is that either someone sees my mistake, or someone can repeat this test and verify that there really is a bug.

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader]::New("C:\UNICODE.txt", $true)
Write-Host "$($reader.CurrentEncoding)"
$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
```

FWIW, I am testing this on Windows 7 with PS updated to 5, but ultimately I need it to work with PS2 as well, due to some unfortunate truths about Architects and software upgrades.

Comment: Please note that UTF-8 is one way to encode Unicode. In UTF-8 the first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single byte with the same binary value as ASCII, so that valid ASCII text is valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: [`CurrentEncoding` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding): The current character encoding used by the current reader. The value can be different after the first call to any Read method of StreamReader, since **encoding autodetection is not done until the first call to a Read method**.

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: @PetSerAl That's good info! I revised my little test script to look at CurrentEncoding after my ReadLine loop and that does work. However, my ultimate goal is to write using StreamWriter to a new file with the same encoding, so I need to get at the encoding before that read loop. I tried using the Peek method in the hopes that that would trigger the Encoding evaluation, but it didn't. So, any recommendation on the best way to get the encoding before the Read loop?

Comment: @PetSerAl Correction, .Peek() does work! And .Peek doesn't doesn't throw an error. I am having a similar issue with StreamWriter, but I'll put that in a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by `StreamReader.CurrentEncoding` comes from the BOM (=byte order mark), which is at the beginning of your file. Take a look at your file with a hex editor and you will see that `EF BB BF` is in the beginning. Each encoding has its own by BOM. All BOMs can be found here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark

With this you can create a bunch of files with the same content, but with different encodings:

```
echo "hello" | Out-File test_UTF8.txt -Encoding UTF8
echo "hello" | Out-File test_UTF32.txt -Encoding UTF32
```

If you look at with a hex editor, you will see `FF FE 00 00` in the beginning.
Please see [Byte Order Mark](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark).

This produces a hex-dump of file `test_UTF32.txt`:

```
$bytes = Get-Content test_UTF32.txt -Encoding Byte
$hexBytes = $bytes | foreach {$_.ToString("X2")}
[string]::Join(" ",$hexBytes)
```

Result:

> FF FE 00 00 68 00 00 00 65 00 00 00 6C 00 00 00 6C 00 00 00 6F 00 00
>   00 0D 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00

And again `FF FE 00 00` denotes encoding `UTF-32 (LE)`.